# How Statamic caches content?

Tags: php, caching, content-management-system, statamic

I would like to try Statamic (file based CMS, http://statamic.com/ ) but I can get no info on its caching strategy. I'm affraid there is a lot of I/O operations especially when using advanced techniques - tagging, using add-ons etc.

Do you have Statamic purchased and can confirm/disprove my concerns?

Comment: I can't see any mention of caching in the docs but the directory structure on [this page](http://statamic.com/docs/how-statamic-works) has a cache directory, try contacting them `gentlemen@statamic.com`

Comment: I like the extra f in afraid for emphasis. Nice work.

Comment: Well, that was entirely subconscious. :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm Statamic's founder, so hopefully this answer will be helpful :)

Statamic 1.6.x keeps a cache file of all the YAML data for all your pages and entries (markdown files with front-loaded YAML). It's stored as a single big php array and updated when files inside your _content/ folder are changed. This lets you have a really high performance site under most conditions.

Statamic 1.7 (not yet released) will break the single cache file into one file per folder (e.g. /blog/, /news/, etc), which will keep any one cache file from getting too large -- an issue present in about .1% of the users.

Does that help? Anything else I could answer?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles on this in 2023, Statamic now uses a concept called "stache" and while you cannot disable it (for whatever reasons you may want to), you can use Antlers tags like `{{ nocache }}` to exclude certain components/pages from the cache.

For reference:

https://statamic.dev/caching#the-stache

https://statamic.dev/static-caching